# Importing DNxHD into DaVinci Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

I converted a .webm file into DNxHD. Unfortunately I'm unable to import it into DaVinci Resolve.

Steps: Import > File > Directory where files are stored.

I'm able to see other, importable files, such as .jpgs but I don't see the DNxHD files.

I'm unable to determine what steps are missing.

Comment: What container file did you create? And also have you tried viewing the video from a media player just to make sure the conversion was successful?

Comment: @BuckHicks  I've converted the webm file into DNxHD,.mov and .mp4. Interesting they all have the same file size!?  I'm using FFMPEG in case that matters. I can open the files in VLC but no other media player.

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you using the paid or free version of DaVinci Resolve?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free version then it could be that you don't have the necessary codecs to import those files.  I was unable to import *.mp4 so I used the following command to convert them to *.mov and that worked fine:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 2015_0101_000056_008.MP4 -c:v dnxhd -vf "scale=1280:720,fps=60000/1001,format=yuv422p" -b:v 110M -c:a pcm_s16le footage08.mov
```